# CodeDom is not available in Portable Class Libary?

Tags: c#, class, portability, codedom

I have recently made a interpreter on .NET 4.5 Framework, intensively written on CodeDom, and I want to port to my window phone 8 device by using Portable Class Libary.

In the Class Explorer, I saw all members of CodeDom namespace in PCL, but even when import all "using" namespaces, I still can't get the project to compile without errors of lack CodeDom.

Can someone give me a hint ?

Comment: No CodeDom in PCL.  Compiling code on a phone is not supported, all code must be part of the app package.  Only way ahead is a true interpreter, look at TouchDevelop.